# CMake configure succeeded but fails to build target due to header not found

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, cmake, vcpkg

I'm trying to build a C++ project with 3rd-party library managed by [`vcpkg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/users/buildsystems/cmake-integration). CMake is able to correctly find the libraries using `find_package` during configuration. However, when I build the target, the compilation always fails with "header file not found error".

### Context

I'm trying to build a C++ project on my Apple M1 laptop. I'm using CMake inside VS Code.

```
$ uname -a
Darwin My-MacBook-Air.local 22.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.4.0: Mon Mar  6 21:00:41 PST 2023; root:xnu-8796.101.5~3/RELEASE_ARM64_T8103 arm64
$ which cmake
/opt/homebrew/bin/cmake
$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.26.3
```

Below is my `settings.json` (from VS Code) and `CMakeList.txt`

```json
{
    "C_Cpp.default.cppStandard": "c++20",
    "cmake.configureOnOpen": true,
    "cmake.configureSettings": {
        "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": "~/Srcs/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
    }
}
```

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.0)
project(myproj VERSION 0.1.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

# headers
include_directories(include)

# create library
add_library(myproj-lib STATIC
    "src/core/crypto_msg.cpp"
    "src/rsa/rsa.cpp"
)

# add external libraries
# openssl
set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR "~/Srcs/vcpkg/installed/arm64-osx")
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(myproj-lib PUBLIC OpenSSL::Crypto)
# fmt
find_package(fmt REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(myproj-lib PUBLIC fmt::fmt)
# range
find_package(range-v3 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(myproj-lib PUBLIC range-v3)

# main func
add_executable(myproj-main main.cpp)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

### Error description

#### Update 1

Adding the following two lines in `CMakeList.txt` as suggested in the comments

```
get_property(dir TARGET fmt::fmt PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
message(STATUS ${dir})
```

I get the following:

```
[cmake] -- /Users/Bob/Srcs/vcpkg/installed/arm64-osx/include
```

Looks like the path is correctly added. Checking `build/compile_commands.json` also shows the path is passed to compiler via `-isystem /Users/Bob/Srcs/vcpkg/installed/arm64-osx/include`:

```
"/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ -I/Users/Bob/myproj/include -isystem /Users/Bob/Srcs/vcpkg/installed/arm64-osx/include -g -std=gnu++17 -arch arm64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk -o CMakeFiles/myproj-lib.dir/src/core/crypto_msg.cpp.o -c /Users/Bob/myproj/src/core/crypto_msg.cpp"
```

---

#### Original description

When I configure the project using the following command, everything seems fine:

```
$ /opt/homebrew/bin/cmake --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:STRING=~/Srcs/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -S/Users/Bob/myproj -B/Users/Bob/myproj/build -G Ninja

[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.5.12050022
[cmake] -- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.5.12050022
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
[cmake] -- Found OpenSSL: /Users/Bob/Srcs/vcpkg/installed/arm64-osx/debug/lib/libcrypto.a (found version "3.1.0")  
[cmake] -- Configuring done (2.6s)
[cmake] -- Generating done (0.0s)
[cmake] -- Build files have been written to: /Users/Bob/myproj/build
```

However, build failed as follows:

```
$/opt/homebrew/bin/cmake --build /Users/Bob/myproj/build --config Debug --target all --

[2/3] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/myproj-main.dir/main.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/myproj-main.dir/main.cpp.o 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++  -I/Users/Bob/myproj/include -g -std=gnu++2a -arch arm64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk -MD -MT CMakeFiles/myproj-main.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/myproj-main.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/myproj-main.dir/main.cpp.o -c /Users/Bob/myproj/main.cpp
In file included from /Users/Bob/myproj/main.cpp:2:
/Users/Bob/myproj/include/core/core.hpp:4:10: fatal error: 'fmt/format.h' file not found
#include <fmt/format.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
(base)
```

Here the issue with `fmt` is just a coincidence, as it's the first included 3rd-party header. In fact, none of the `vcpkg`-managed libraries can be linked. The `#include` statement fails for all of them.

Where did I go wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: As I know that AppleClang doesn't support C++20. `-std=gnu++2a` confirms this.

Comment: @273K That doesn't seem to be the root reason. Even if I set it to `-std=gnu++14`, same issue still happens. And if I don't use CMake, but rather include the dependencies manually via e.g. `-I/path/to/fmt/include`, then it compiles.

Comment: @user Thanks! Updated in the problem description. The `get_property` result looks correct. The `compile_commands.json` also has `-isystem /Users/Bob/Srcs/vcpkg/installed/arm64-osx/include`. Looks innocent.

Comment: You show now `-std=gnu++17` in your update. `fmt` is a library of C++20, not of C++17 nor C++2a.

Comment: @273K Ah, that's because I was just tweaking the options and changed c++20 to c++17. So the content of the file is also modified. But the same error appears also. In fact, even if I remove all usage of fmt, the including other libraries (e.g. `range-v3`) results in the same "header not found" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for adding the `get_property` check and checking your compile_commands.json file like I asked.

I might be wrong / misread, but I don't see anything where you specify that your `myproj-main` target should link to the `fmt::fmt` target. You *do* link `fmt::fmt` with `PUBLIC` to your `myproj-lib` target, but that won't automatically make your `myproj-main` target link to `fmt::fmt` as well, *unless* you `target_link_libraries(myproj-main PRIVATE myproj-lib)`. So either you do that (depends on if you actually meant to do that in the first place or not- don't do that if you didn't), or you `target_link_libraries(myproj-main PRIVATE fmt::fmt)`.

I assume that what you're showing from your compile_commands.json is for a source file *other than* your main.cpp, because if it was, then you wouldn't be getting this include error at all.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. I made a really silly mistake. Thank you for pointing it out!